# Checking awkward array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like following.

```
$ => Array (2)
(
|    ['0'] => Array (2)
|    (
|    |    ['0'] = String(1) "2"
|    |    ['1'] = String(1) "2"
|    )
|    ['1'] => Array (2)
|    (
|    |    ['0'] = String(1) "2"
|    |    ['1'] = String(1) "1"
|    )
)
```

But could also be bigger or smaller having only one array.

Each array represents a row of result that have been returned from a database.

The first field [0][0] is a ID number which is going to be needed.

[0][1] is the value I need to check.

I need to know whether it is present or not, say whether I got a 2 or a 1 or whether I didn't.

If I didn't then I need to send the ID ([0][0]) off to another function.

Sometimes I may end up with more results or less. So this needs to be done using loops but am struggling to get it right, each time I think I have some code that will work it won't.

Can anyone help out?

Edit:

This is what I got so far...

```
$tweet_sentiment = array();
$analyzer = array();
foreach($get_sentiment as $sentiment) {
    $tweet_id = $sentiment[0];
    $analyzer[] = $sentiment[1];
    $tweet_sentiment[$tweet_id] = $analyzer;
}
```

This changes the way the arrays look into the following:

```
$ => Array (1)
(
|    ['2'] => Array (2)
|    (
|    |    ['0'] = String(1) "2"
|    |    ['1'] = String(1) "1"
|    )
)
```

Comment: What are the conditions of "I didn't"?  You didn't what?

Comment: Can you post the code you've got so far?

Comment: I've added a code example of what I have so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing a few of the internal SQL statements so that my result from the database was different.

I found that the SQL statements I were using and the returned arrays were too complex to process in the way I wanted - mainly due to how it was formatted by the SQL query results.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understand your question.

A first loop goes through the main array and works on its index => array2.

The 2nd loop goes through that second array and check if the value of that array is "value1". If it is, it executes `doWhenValueIsThere()` otherwise it executes `doWhenValueIsNotThere()`.

You have to create the two functions depending on your needs.

```
  foreach ($array1 as $index => $array2) 
  {
    foreach (array_keys($array2) as $id)
    {
       if ($array2[$id] == "value1") doWhenValueIsThere();
       else doWhenValueIsNotThere();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem with a little alteration... 

                        if($array2[$id] != '2' && $array2[$id] == '1') {
                            function1();
                        } else if($array2[$id] != '1' && $array2[$id] == '2') {
                            function2();
                        }

Comment: Although actually is this checking the first or second value in the array?

Comment: This isn't actually working as its using both values to check. I need to just check the one value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do the check like this:

`array_key_exists(1, $x[1]) ? $x[1][1] : otherFunction($x[0][0])`

where $x is your array.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$tweet_sentiment = array();
$analyzer = array();
foreach($get_sentiment as $sentiment) {
    $tweet_id = $sentiment[0];
    if(isset($sentiment[1])){
      $analyzer[] = $sentiment[1];
      $tweet_sentiment[$tweet_id] = $analyzer;
    }
}
?>
```